# Realizar una consulta en laravel teniendo en cuenta dos tablas

Tags: php, sql, laravel, base-de-datos

Me gustaría que no se repitiesen los campos id y descripción 3 veces, porque solamente quiero que las uris se agrupen en un array o algo parecido. Necesitaría que solamente se mostrara un campo para un elemento del array como los siguientes datos y no que se repitieran tres veces y que se pareciera al siguiente objeto(solamente tengo en cuenta un elemento del array con sus datos).

**Me gustaría obtener los datos, parecidos al siguiente código**

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "descripcion": "Bar con especialidad en tapas 
    valencianas.",
  "uri": "bar-interior.jpg1664990505.jpg",
         "cafe-bar.jpg1664990505.jpg",
         "comida.jpg1664990505.jpg"   
 },
 {
  "id":2
 .
 .
 .    
 ]
```

**Tengo realizada la siguiente consulta**

```
 $query = DB::table('servicios as s')
   ->join('fotos as f', 's.id', '=', 'f.id_servicio')
   ->select('s.id','s.descripcion','s.id','f.uri')    
   ->get();
```

**Datos obtenidos**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "descripcion": "Bar con especialidad en tapas valencianas.",
    "uri": "bar-interior.jpg1664990505.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "descripcion": "Bar con especialidad en tapas valencianas.",
    "uri": "cafe-bar.jpg1664990505.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "descripcion": "Bar con especialidad en tapas valencianas.",
    "uri": "comida.jpg1664990505.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "descripcion": "Platos típicos de la comarca.",
    "uri": "bar-interior.jpg1665069019.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "descripcion": "Platos típicos de la comarca.",
    "uri": "cafe-bar.jpg1665069020.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "descripcion": "Platos típicos de la comarca.",
    "uri": "comida.jpg1665069020.jpg"
},
.
.
.
```

]

**Tablas utilizadas**

[image: Tabla servicios]

[image: Tabla fotos]

Comment: Podrías agrupar y concatenar los datos de la columna que te interesa. Como punto de partida, algo así en mysql https://stackoverflow.com/a/149799/7498116

Comment: gracias, tu respuesta me ayudó!!

Answer (score 1):

Vale, la respuesta es esta

```
$sql = "SELECT s.id, s.nombre, s.descripcion, GROUP_CONCAT(f.uri) AS 'uris' FROM `fotos` as f,`servicios` as s WHERE s.`id`= f.`id_servicio` GROUP BY s.`id`, s.`nombre`, s.`descripcion`";

$query = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```